# What's way get to list queuename using ip server rabbit in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rabbitmq

I have ip server rabbit but I want get list queue about to management and handle it. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

you can install **Management plugin** https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html and can manage and see the queue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: can i use c# code to get the value instead of rabbit plugin?